# No AuthenticationProvider found on refresh token - Spring OAuth2 java config

Tags: java, spring, authentication, oauth, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project in which I've configured a Spring OAuth2 authentication process which partially works. I can authenticate OK but when I'm trying to get a refresh token I get an exception.

OAuth configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "xxx";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Value("${clientDetailsService.clientName}")
        private String clientName;

        @Value("${clientDetailsService.clientSecret}")
        private String clientSecret;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("tokenServices")
        private AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("codeServices")
        private AuthorizationCodeServices codeServices;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("requestFactory")
        private OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("tokenGranter")
        private TokenGranter tokenGranter;

        private final TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            endpoints.tokenServices(tokenServices)
                        .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                        .authorizationCodeServices(codeServices)
                        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                        .requestFactory(requestFactory)
                        .tokenGranter(tokenGranter);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }


        @Bean(name = "tokenGranter")
        @Primary
        public TokenGranter tokenGranter() {
            final List<TokenGranter> tokenGranters = new ArrayList<TokenGranter>();

            tokenGranters.add(new AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter(tokenServices, codeServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new RefreshTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new ImplicitTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new ClientCredentialsTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new CustomTokenGranter(authenticationManager, tokenServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory));

            return new CompositeTokenGranter(tokenGranters);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService(){
            final InMemoryClientDetailsServiceBuilder builder = new InMemoryClientDetailsServiceBuilder();
            builder.withClient(clientName)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret(clientSecret);

            try {
                return builder.build();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Bean(name = "tokenServices")
        @Primary
        public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
            final DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            return tokenServices;
        }

        @Bean(name = "requestFactory")
        @Primary
        public OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory() {
            return new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean(name = "codeServices")
        @Primary
        public AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices();
        }
    }
```

I also have some custom components defined, like a custom Token Granter, custom authentication provider etc. I'll post them if necessary.

As I said, authentication flow works OK. When I POST to /oauth/token I get a token and a refresh token, but when I then try to exchange my refresh token for a new token (by POSTing http://localhost:8080/oauth/token with grant_type=refresh_token and refresh_token=my refresh token) I get an exception:

**No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken**

Where do I set the authentication provider? How do I get Spring to use my custom authentication provider for refresh tokens also?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this by explicitly defining a PreAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component("preAuthProvider")
public class CustomPreAuthProvider extends PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userService;

    public CustomPreAuthProvider(){
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        super.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userService);
    }
}
```

and then a custom userservice:

```
@Service
public class CustomPreAuthUserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

    @Override
    public final UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) {
    ...    
    }
}
```

and adding this provider to the oauth2 config:

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("preAuthProvider")
private AuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).authenticationProvider(preAuthProvider);
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, but can you guide me a little on what have to do on loadUserDetails? Thanks

Comment: Well `loadUserDetails` is where you load the requesting user. How you do this (from a DB, from memory, via a web service call) is up to your implementation. @AciD

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative way to Jesper's answer, if you want to reuse your current `UserDetailsService` for this purpose, you can just do it the same way as Spring does it with their `DefaultTokenServices`:

```
@Bean
public CustomTokenServices tokenServices() {
    CustomTokenServices tokenServices = new CustomTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    tokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(false);
    tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(createPreAuthProvider());
    return tokenServices;
}

private ProviderManager createPreAuthProvider() {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>(userDetailsService));
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(provider));
}
```

`UserDetailsService` is autowired into this `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 2):

I can not be disagree with Jesper's answer, but in my case, that same error has been fixed removing:

```
tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
```

from `tokenService()`

Comment: Not setting the authenticationManager "fixes" the error, but I wouldn't recommend it. I've debugged spring's `DefaultTokenServices` and refreshing the token does not perform re-authentication if authenticationManager is null, which means it will never step into `UserDetailsService` to check if an account is still active, not blocked etc.